# transpose row into column using join of two table without duplication of row using mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

I have two tables and want to transpose rows into columns with the normal query only. When transposing data should not be repeated. if there is duplicate data then that data should be combined into a single row.

Below is the basic result set that I want to pivot/convert/transpose
[image]

If I use

SELECT
name, SUM(case when country = 'Aus' then FORMAT((cop*100)/cp,2) end) as `Aus`, SUM(case when country = 'France' then FORMAT((cop*100)/cp,2) end) as `France`
..........
group by name

Instead of

select name, case when country = 'Aus' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ", cp) end AS `Aus`, case when country = 'France' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ", cp) end AS `France`
.......
group by name,country,cop,cp

Then data will come correct but the format is incorrect because if we will use the CONCAT inside sum function then this will truncate the value.

[image]

companies

| id | name | country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Skidoo | France |
| 5 | Pixope | France |
| 6 | Syd | Aus |
| 8 | Skidoo | Aus |

campaigns

| company_id | expenses | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 | 50 |
| 4 | 10 | 60 |
| 5 | 15 | 30 |
| 5 | 10 | 40 |
| 8 | 5 | 25 |
| 6 | 60 | 120 |

Result be like:

| name | Aus | France |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pixope | NULL | 32.14% of 140 |
| Skidoo | 25.00% of 80 | 67.86% of 140 |
| Syd | 75.00% of 80 | NULL |

But getting:

| name | Aus | France |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pixope | NULL | 32.14% of 140 |
| Skidoo | 25.00% of 80 | NULL |
| Skidoo | NULL | 67.86% of 140 |
| Syd | 75.00% of 80 | NULL |

Where data like 25.00% of 80

80 - is total profit(sum of diff b/w revenue and expenses) of all company in the specific country.
25.00% - is %age of specific company in the total profit of all company in specific country.

---

### Transpose query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
    'case when country = ''',country,''' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ",cp) end AS `',country,'`'
) SEPARATOR ', ') INTO @sql FROM companies;
  
SET @sql = CONCAT('
select name,', @sql, '
from (
    select name,country,
    (
        SELECT SUM(revenue-expenses)
        from companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on cc.company_id = c.id Where c.id = companies.id
    ) as cop,
    (
        SELECT 
        SUM(revenue-expenses) as b
        FROM companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on c.id = cc.company_id where c.country = companies.country
    ) as cp
    from companies
    
) as final
group by name,country,cop,cp
order by name
');
select @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

---

### Raw Query

```
select name,case when country = 'Aus' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ",cp) end AS `Aus`, case when country = 'France' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ",cp) end AS `France`
from (
    select name,country,
    (
        SELECT SUM(revenue-expenses)
        from companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on cc.company_id = c.id Where c.id = companies.id
    ) as cop,
    (
        SELECT 
        SUM(revenue-expenses) as b
        FROM companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on c.id = cc.company_id where c.country = companies.country
    ) as cp
    from companies
    
) as final
group by name,country,cop,cp
order by name
```

Comment: Please don't spam the tags; just tag the technologies related to your question. The above appears to have nothing to do with PHP or SQL Server, and it's not asking specifically about database files/objects/design, so I've removed those tags.

Comment: This site gives a good explanation of the types of JOINS .. INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/CROSS  etc...  if you have 2 tables and you are joining the data, its important to pick the right type of JOIN so you get only the results you want.  (citation -
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join.asp    )

Comment: Also do you have an example of what "combing them into a single row for duplicates" would look like?  How should it handle the data?  Which value is the real value?  You have 2 different results in each database for some reason, so that is curious.  Could you be alright just dropping all cases of NULL?   Do a test for ISNULL(variable) and if its NULL then perhaps it would ignore the NULL value and use the other value instead in the other table.

Comment: The value of the country combines them into a single row. The issue is with concat function. we are doing sum of name and sum of country based on duplicate value in country we are combining in to single row. we are gettting two result set because we are doing group with name and country nut in the result set we have to group with name only but that is not going to possible some how. We can handle null but not required at that time GROUP_CONCAT put NULL by default.

Comment: problem is that name and country are nonaggregated columns not functionally dependent on each other so it becomes necessary to group by name and country.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(
'MAX(case when country = ''',country,''' then CONCAT(FORMAT(cop*100/cp,2),"% of ",cp) end) AS `',country,'`'
)) INTO @sql FROM companies;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT name, ',@sql,'
FROM
(
    select name,country,
    (
        SELECT SUM(revenue-expenses)
        from companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on cc.company_id = c.id 
        where c.name = companies.name and c.country = companies.country
    ) as cop,
    (
        SELECT 
        SUM(revenue-expenses)
        FROM companies c
        inner join campaigns cc on c.id = cc.company_id 
        where c.country = companies.country
    ) as cp
    FROM companies
) as final
GROUP BY name
order by name
');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```